# Is Grails (using GGTS & MySQL) supposed to create a database

Tags: mysql, grails, ggts

I'm a newbie and I am trying to connect to a MySQL database, but I'm getting this error

> "Error 2015-07-23 07:53:55,288 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR
>   pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
>   Message: Unknown database 'mytest'"

I understand that I need to have a database called `mytest`, but I don't know how to do that from GGTS. Advice appreciated!

Comment: you can do it from mysql client, any of them

Comment: Okay, that worked.  I used MySql Dashboard.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/12/connecting-grails-to-mysql-and-others/ would be perfect solution for your question.

Each and every step to link GGTS with MySql is clearly mentioned.